# Wordpress - images not syncing in AWS EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, wordpress, amazon-ebs

I think I know the answer, but I'd like to confirm.

I've a 2-servers load balancer that's hosting a Wordpress website.
When the content managers create new content, specially IMAGES: intermittently the image fail to load. After few refresh , it's loads fine.

So I decided to open both servers, and yes: There is no sync between servers. The WP website is not using S3 to store the media and a image may be in a server and sometimes not in the another.

How to solve this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use S3 (check whether keys are present and the server is configured properly) and point your images there. Alternatively, you can save the images to a NFS-mounted volume on one of the machines (or on a third machine, or on an Elastic Filesystem) and serve them from there. This way all images will reside on a single volume and no synchronization is required.

If you use an EFS (in essence, a volume at AWS you mount via NFS) or a third server you can make all the front-ends identical and use any cookie-cutter approach you see fit to create and destroy them as needed.